# How to clip a PSTricks image to its boundaries

Tags: pstricks

I have a PSTricks `pspicture` where certain elements go beyond the boundaries of the Image itself. I tried using `\clipbox`, but that either completely removed the entire image or didn't change anything at all.

I am not very knowledgeable about PSTricks, there might be an obvious solution, but I am completely unable to find it.

The image is included as

```
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(180,125)
    % stuff...
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Use the `pspicture*` environment (with a star).

Comment: @Bernard That was way too obvious. Thank you - I must have overread that in the documentation. I was importing an image from Inkscape, and for some reason that doesnt add the * to its images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to clip a picture to the size of the `pspicture` environment, you just have to use the `pspicture*` environment (with a star).

Alternatively, you can clip with a closed path using, for instance,

```
\begin{psclip}{\psellipse(0,0){4}{2.5}}
 .........
\end{psclip}
```

which clips the contents of the environment with the ellipse centred at $(0,0)$, with semi-axes $4$ and $2.5$ units.